# Recursive prolog： Compare the elements of the first two lists less than or equal to the third list

Tags: prolog

we should do a recursive prolog program. If the total number of elements in List1 and List2 is less than or equal to the number of elements in List, then output is true.

```
?- list([a,b,c],[1,2,3],[q,w,e,r]).
No
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be extremely simple.

```
list(L1, L2, L3) :- length(L1, A1), length(L2, A2), length(L3, A3), A3 >= A1 + A2.
```

You can alternatively write your own `length` function, you can do as below (it's named `len`, and you must change code provided above, AKA change `length` to `len`).

```
len([], 0).
len([_ | R], X) :- len(R, Y), X is Y + 1.
```

*EDIT:*

To achieve *"pure"* recursion, you can do as below.

```
list([], [], [_ | _]) :- !.
list([], [], []).
list([], [_ | R], [_ | T]) :- list([], R, T), !.
list([_ | R], [], [_ | T]) :- list(R, [], T), !.
list([_ | R1], [_ | R2], [_, _ | T]) :- list(R1, R2, T), !.
```

Comment: The question specifically says "using recursion". So we guess that the idea is to iterate through all three lists, somehow, until something.

Comment: @TA_intern True, I've updated the answer to consist exclusively of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Most recursive problems have 1 or 2 "special cases" that terminate the recursion. Given your constraint in the problem statement,

> We should do a recursive prolog program.
>
> If the total number of elements in List1 and List2 is less than or equal to the number of elements in List, then output is true.

For the sake of discussion, let us refer to the 3 lists as `A`, `B` and `C`.

If `A`, `B`, and `C` are all empty, the constraint is satisfied and we succeed. We can express that as

```
list( [], [], [] ).
```

If `A` and `B` are empty, but `C` is not, the constraint is satisified, and we succeeed. We can express that as

```
list( [], [], [_|_] ).
```

If `A` is empty, but `B` and `C` are not, we just need to remove the head of both `B` and `C` and recurse down:

```
list( [], [_|Bs], [_|Cs] ) :- list([],Bs,Cs).
```

And similarly, if `A` and `C` are non-empty, but `B` is empty, we can just remove the head of both `A` and `C` and recurse down:

```
list( [_|As], [], [_|Cs] ) :- list(As,[],Cs).
```

If `A`, `B`, and `C` are all non-empty, and `C` contains at least two items, we can remove all 3 heads and recurse down:

```
list( [_|As], [_|Bs], [_,_|Cs] ) :- list(As,Bs,Cs).
```

That should about do it. Any case where `C` is exhausted, but `A` or `B` is not will fail by not finding a solution.

Putting it all together, we get this:

```
list(     [] ,     [] ,       [] ) .                  % A+B =  C
list(     [] ,     [] ,   [_|Cs] ) .                  % A+B <  C
list(     [] , [_|Bs] ,   [_|Cs] ) :- list([],Bs,Cs). % 0+B <= C
list( [_|As] ,     [] ,   [_|Cs] ) :- list(As,[],Cs). % A+0 <= C
list( [_|As] , [_|Bs] , [_,_|Cs] ) :- list(As,Bs,Cs). % A+B <= C
```

A lot of Prolog programming is learning to pattern match in the heads of your predicates, so in the above, you'll see that literally all the logic is in the head of each term.

And Prolog is a *descriptive language*: you describe the solution and let the inference engine determine the truth or falsity of your proposition. So, we

- Define what *success* looks like:
  Formal logic holds that that all that which is not true is false,
  making truth univalued.
- Define the conditions that let us get closer to success (in this case, successively removing items from the list(s) until you either find success, or run out of alternatives.